# Query Twitter Rate Limit API from CURL

Tags: curl, twitter

I'm trying to get my head around on how to query the twitter rate limit api

```
[/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json][1]


 curl https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json
```

I get this

```
  {"errors":[{"message":"Bad Authentication data","code":215}]}
```

Now I know it require authentication data but how do I pass it in a **get** request.

My assumption it is  `header` (I have to pass authentication data) but the question what format ?

Any Clue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Twitter API requires that you authenticate to it using OAuth. The `curl` command-line tool does not directly support this form of authentication — while [it is possible to negotiate manually](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/14460), it's rather complicated, and I wouldn't recommend it. There is probably a Twitter API library available for your programming environment; use that instead!

Note that the rate limit status is specific to the user or application that requests it. It's not meaningful on its own.

Answer (score 0):

The curl command will look something like this, where XXX will be input by you and YYY will be auto-generated:

```
curl --get 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/application/rate_limit_status.json' --header 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="XXX", oauth_nonce="YYY", oauth_signature="YYY", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_timestamp="1402837400", oauth_token="XXX", oauth_version="1.0"' --verbose
```

You can preform this generation using tools like:
http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/example/signature.html

You can also download twitter's twurl tool, which will make your life much easier than using curl directly.
http://thechangelog.com/twurl-oauth-enabled-curl-for-the-twitter-api/